# How can I setup and use factory_girl_rails properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot

I think I have a problem with configuring FactoryGirl with rails. I initially followed [ASCIIcasts #275: how i test](http://railscasts.com/episodes/275-how-i-test?view=asciicast), but rake is giving me `NameError: uninitialized constant ...`

Am I missing something? Is it possible that some config file are wrong? I'm pretty new to RSpec and Rails.

I'm using **Rails 3.2.2** + **Mongoid** + **RSpec** + **factory_girl_rails**.

**Error:**

```
Failures:

  1) User should save user with valid required fields
     Failure/Error: let(:user) { FactoryGirl.build(:valid_user) }
     NameError:
       uninitialized constant ValidUser
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**spec/factories.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :valid_user do
    name     'somename'
    email    'a@b.com'
    password 'somepassword'
  end
end
```

**spec/models/user_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.build(:valid_user) }

  it "should save user with valid required fields" do
    user.should be_valid
  end
end
```

**spec/spec_helper.rb**

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'capybara/rspec'

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's usually helpful to output the whole error, or at least the whole first sentence -- you haven't even told us what the missing constant is!

UPDATE: Thanks for the whole error. When you define the factory :valid_user, Factory Girl will automatically assume it is for a model named `ValidUser`. To get around this, you can either name your factory `:user` (assuming you have a `User` model), or you can try:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :valid_user, :class => User do
    name     'somename'
    email    'a@b.com'
    password 'somepassword'
  end
end
```

Alternatively, if you want to have a couple different types of User factories, you can use:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    # set some attrs
  end

  factory :valid_user, :parent => :user do
    name     'somename'
    email    'a@b.com'
    password 'somepassword'
  end

  factory :invalid_user, :parent => :user do
    # some other attrs
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added the whole error message. Apparently, `Factory.build` will soon be deprecated. (DEPRECATION WARNING: Factory.build is deprecated; use FactoryGirl.build instead.)

Comment: Wow, silly me! I should have wondered how should factory girl guess the model! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare factory like this........

```
 Factory.define :organization do |g|
   g.name 'Test Organization'
   g.phone_number '5345234561'
   g.website_url 'www.testorg.com'
   g.city 'chichago '
   g.association :state

 end
```

And use it in organization_spec like this.....

```
require 'spec_helper'

 describe Organization do
    before :each do
     @state = Factory :state
     @organization = Factory :organization ,:state => @state
    end

  it "should be invalid without a name" do
    @organization.name = nil
    @organization.should_not be_valid
 end

end
```

And enjoy!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I followed exactly what you said, but the problem still exists. :( I think the problem is with my config files. Can you explain how can I setup factory_girl_rails? What config files should I change?